# Are two typelists spliceable in a constant time?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, splice, typelist

I'm working a bit with typelists defined in Alexandrescu's Modern C++ Design.
In his books, he talks about Appending a type to a typelist, but he doesn't talk about splicing two typelists...

I guess it is possible to splice two typelists using the Append functionnality, but wouldn't it result in a linear-time splicing (whereas std::list::splice is O(1) ). ?

Well, i know that this computation time can be considered as "free" as it is compile-time, but I am curious :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typelist concept is *usually** closer to the Computer Science notion of a list than the (doubly) linked list that `std::list` is. The two ideas share a name but have crucial differences.

Since metaprograms are purely functional you can't modify in-place an input typelist the way `std::list::splice` does: you have to 'generate' the output typelist(s), which would be linear. (Laziness can be used to defer and reduce that cost however; the exact cost paid would then depend on the final algorithm.)

*: I said usually because the Boost.MPL supports things like iterators and views which blurs the line, at least from the user point-of-view.

(For the sake of the argument assume that by "CS" list here I meant the cons cell + the empty list.)

Comment: `std::list` is a perfectly valid example of a "Computer Science" list. CS deals with mutable data structures as well, and `std::list` is a perfectly ordinary example of a doubly linked list. Perhaps you meant that it is closer to the *functional programming* concept of a list (which is singly linked and immutable)?

Comment: @jalf I didn't want to give a reference for a definition of a "CS" list, I don't think that's quite relevant to what's at hand. The first paragraph is only meant as a warning to **not** assume that the operations available on a typelist are similar to those available on `std::list` *on the basis of the name alone*. The second paragraph is where it's at (and the crux of the matter here is *pure* FP).